# What is Dimensionality Reduction ? Feature Selection or extraction

Tags: data-science, feature-extraction, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

In my knowledge, DR is a technique that transforms high dimensional data into lower dimension. But is it feature selection or feature extraction? Do the features are only SELECTED from the available features or are they engineered?
(Was asked in some test - had to choose from feature selection and extraction)

Comment: The question is a little unfair as it eventually ends up being both, but dimensionality reduction selects features in higher dimensions and reduces them down to a lower dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dimensionality-reduction/info) for `data-reduction` states:

> *"In machine learning and statistics, dimensionality reduction or dimension reduction is the process of reducing the number of random variables under consideration, **and can be divided into feature selection and feature extraction**."*

So:

> But is it feature selection or feature extraction?

It is either one or the other.

> Do the features are only SELECTED from the available features or are they engineered?

Again, I think the answer is either one or the other.  (I don't know what you mean by "engineered" in this context.)

---

If this is not helping you understand, I suggest:

- Ask a more detailed / specific question
- Read the Wikipedia articles on:

  - [Dimensionality Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)
  - [Feature Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection)
  - [Feature Extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction)
  - and so on.